# native sharing dialogue on android webview? is it possible?

Tags: android, webview, share, android-sharing, socialshare

Can I have a button that calls the android native share dialogue on android webview? For example uing Javascript in the webview and call my android function? If so, how can I make it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can expose your own methods to Javascript in the WebView by using the WebView's [addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) method.

From that method, you can 'share' your data, whatever that is.
You can't "call" the share dialog directly, though. You need to use an Intent - in this case, probably an [ACTION_SEND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) intent.